# Wordpress: Change the "site_url" for a few pages

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

We are out of ideas. We also tried a lot.

In Wordpress we need to change the "site_url" for a few pages (because also the scripts, images, etc. need to work without much changes). The remaining pages keep the normal site_url.

Reason: We want to use a Shared SSL that looks like:
https://www.the-shared-ssl.com/www.our-website.com

So we need to change the site_url for these few pages (not all pages).

We tried the Wordpress HTTPS plugin, it doesnt work with our hoster.
We also tried to put an "if" statement into the wp-config.php, it also doesn't work.
It would be good if there's a solution without htaccess

Is there a code guru that can help us?

Answer (score 0):

site_url() calls the function get_site_url() which looks up the option in your wp_options table called "site_url." Changing the config file won't have any impact on it.

What you can do is apply a filter to site_url on the pages where you need to use something else. The last part of the get_site_url() function reads:

```
return apply_filters('site_url', $url, $path, $scheme, $blog_id);
```

So if you want to modify the value that is returned add something like this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'modify_site_url');

function modify_site_url(){
/** check if you're on one of the pages that requires the change */
if(is_page(array('page-one', 'page-two'))){
 add_filter('site_url', 'new_site_url', 10, 4);
}
}


function new_site_url($url, $path, $scheme, $blog_id){
 /** modify the url here */
 $url = whatever you want it to be;
return $url;
}
```

In the new_site_url function it's not using the additional parameters ($path, $scheme, $blog_id) but you could use those to further refine how the url is modified.

Comment: Looking at your question again, I may have misunderstood your intent. If you're trying to have certain pages actually use a different URL, not just change the value of site_url, then you'd have to look into something like a 301 redirect plugin. site_url() won't impact what the actual page URL (in your browser address bar) is.